# Why I can't save any new CMS page or block in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, varnish, magento-cloud, fastly

I'm using Magento 2.4 and when I try to save any CMS block or page I got this screen below, saying **The requested URL was rejected.**

[image: Magento 2 Cloud - The requested URL was rejected.]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a timeout issue. You can exceed time out limitation.

1. For Staging/Production, increase the Fastly timeout - go to **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Fastly Configuration**, set the Admin Path Timeout to 600, then click on Upload VCL to Fastly

[image: Magento Fastly VCL timeout]

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/cdn/trouble-fastly.html#errors

2. Create a new Custom VCL rule in order to increase the timeout via the admin panel. You can create a new **fetch** rule with this code below, remember to change the **admin** to your custom admin URL.

```
if ( req.url ~ "^/(index\.php/)?admin/" ) {
  set bereq.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}
```

[image: Magento 2 Fastly VCL rules]

3. For all environments, you can set the PHP timeout in php.ini in the application/repository root, commit it to GIT and redeploy.

You can set `max_execution_time` / `memory_limit` on your Magento project root push/deploy.

```
max_execution_time = 3600
```

Please follow the document.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-conf-files_magento-app.html#customize-phpini-settings